# Mapping a function of two arguments where the 2nd arg has a fixed value

Tags: map

I create three random images:

```
i1 = Image[RandomReal[1, {8, 12, 3}]];
i2 = Image[RandomReal[1, {8, 12, 3}]];
i3 = Image[RandomReal[1, {8, 12, 3}]];
```

I can scale a single image with

```
ImageResize[i1, Scaled[50]]
```

How can I map `ImageScaled` to all of them

```
ImageResize /@ {i1, i2, i3}
```

using the `Scaled[50]` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ImageResize[#, Scaled[50]]& /@ {i1, i2, i3}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but there is no closing parenthesis, even if I add the parenthesis it only prints ImageScaled[#1, {Scaled[50], Scaled[50], Scaled[50]}]

Comment: @user2019001. Thanks for pointing out my typo. Try the edited version.

Comment: Thanks for editing, the answer you gave is correct but I put the wrong command, it should be ImageResize, however this worked, thanks.