# Using Map with functions that take a parameter

Tags: map

I have a list

```
l={{0, 0, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 1, 2}}
```

And I would like to obtain the number of zeros in each sublist:

```
NZ=Table[Count[l[[i]], 0], {i, Length[l]}]
```

which will return the list: `{3,3,2}` .

Is there a way to use `Map` to accomplish this more cleanly?

What I would like to do is write something like: `Map[Count, l]` which will of course fail because `Count` needs a pattern to count.

Comment: Also have a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11803/map-w-multiple-arguments) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39990/mapping-a-function-of-two-arguments-where-the-2nd-arg-has-a-fixed-value) (I am sure there were still more).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I duplicated previous posts. I searched but it often isn't obvious what to search for.